# Using alt key in omap mappings

Tags: vim

I'm unable to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in omap mappings in Linux. For eg.

```
nmap <A-w> w
```

works properly and behaves identically to <kbd>w</kbd>. However, the following doesn't.

```
omap <A-w> w
```

doesn't work as expected in Ubuntu but does in Windows. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm using gvim but my menubar has been disabled so  doesn't open the gvim Menu.

Comment: vim in Terminal? how did you know `nmap` worked? did you try `nmap <A-a> w` and check it again?

Comment: I'm using gvim. I know it worked because pressing Alt+w in normal mode produces the same motion as 'w'. However, pressing d+Alt+w does not delete the word. However, both :nmap <A-w> and :omap <A-w> show that they're mapped to 'w'.

Comment: I tried `omap <A-a>`, it worked. a-w will trigger the gvim menu here. is that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Realized that this was happening because the  key is mapped to the  key in Ubuntu Unity. This was somehow interfering with my Vim setup. Once I changed that key, everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `omap` is ok. Since you mentioned that you work with gvim. I guess when you press `<A-w>`, it will trigger the menu of gvim. If this is your problem, you could:

```
:set wak=no
```

to solve it.

`:h 'wak'` for detail

Comment: Hello Kent, I've disabled the menu bar in gvim so <A-w> doesn't trigger the gvim menu. After `omap <A-w> w` try pressing `d<A-w>`. If the omap executed successfully then it should delete a word which is not happening.